# Passing file data from .Net backend to Javascript front-end

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, vb.net

I have a .Net (VB/C#) backend on one server and a javascript/jquery front-end on another. I am attempting to pass file data from the backend to the front-end by reading the file in .Net as a byte array, converting it to a base64 string and passing that to the js front-end along with a variable indicating the file type.

Once the data is in the js front-end I attempt to convert the base64 string to a file blob in order to read it with readAsDataURL() so that it can be displayed in an iframe or downloaded by the client.

For testing I am using a pdf file. The process of passing the data works but the file data is not recognized by the pdf viewer. The iframe loads the viewer but I get a message about the file not being recognized as a pdf file.

I have done a tone of searching and have gotten a lot of questions answered by searching stackoverflow but this eludes me.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thank you.

**Update:**
Here is my VB.Net code:

```
     Sub OnReadFileToViewer(ByVal filePath As String)
        Dim okToView As Boolean = False
        Dim fileBLOB As String = String.Empty
        Dim fileEncoded As String = String.Empty
        If (file.Exists(filePath)) Then
            Try
                Using fRead As FileStream = New FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
                    Dim bytes() As Byte = New Byte((CType(fRead.Length, Integer)) - 1) {}
                    Dim numBytesToRead As Integer = CType(fRead.Length, Integer)
                    Dim numBytesRead As Integer = 0

                    While (numBytesToRead > 0)
                        ' Read may return anything from 0 to numBytesToRead.
                        Dim n As Integer = fRead.Read(bytes, numBytesRead, _
                            numBytesToRead)
                        ' Break when the end of the file is reached.
                        If (n = 0) Then
                            Exit While
                        End If
                        numBytesRead = (numBytesRead + n)
                        numBytesToRead = (numBytesToRead - n)

                    End While
                    numBytesToRead = bytes.Length
                    fileEncoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(bytes)
                End Using
                okToView = True
            Catch ex As Exception
                '
            End Try
        End If

        If (okToView) Then
            ' Code to send data to js fron-end
        End If

    End Sub
```

And my js front-end for converting the base64 string to BLOB and the iframe preview:

```
    function PreviewFile(file) {
      var fileBlob = b64toBlob(file,'application/pdf','');
      var reader = new FileReader();
      var fileType = e.target.getAttribute("type");
      alert(fileType);
      reader.onload = function (e) {
         if (fileType)
           $("#fileViewerDiv").append('<iframe id="fileVieweriFrame" class="fileViewer"></iframe>'); // + e.target.result + '">');
           $("#fileVieweriFrame").attr('src', file); //e.target.result);
           $("#fileVieweriFrame").dialog();
          }
     reader.readAsDataURL(fileBlob);
    }

    function b64toBlob(b64Data, contentType, sliceSize) {
      contentType = contentType || '';
      sliceSize = sliceSize || 512;

      var byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
      var byteArrays = [];

      for (var offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
          var slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

          var byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
          for (var i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
             byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
          }

          var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);

          byteArrays.push(byteArray);
       }

      var blob = new Blob(byteArrays, {type: contentType});
      return blob;
 }
```

The alert(fileType) does display the correct file type - application/pdf.

I have to admit that I lifted the b64toBlob() function from a blog somewhere but I have forgotten which one and have lost the URL to the site. My apologies to the original author. If anyone recognizes the code and knows the author/site please let me know

**Edit**
b64toBlob() by Jeremy Banks - [Based on this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript/16245768#16245768)

Comment: are you using ASP.NET?

Comment: Please share the snippet of client side JS that is reading the data and also the server side response along with the content type being sent. That would be of much more help in understanding the issue.

Comment: @DLeh The backend is not using ASP.NET.

Comment: @Vaibhav Code added.

Comment: Original `b64toBlob()` may be from [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16245768/2391294) by Jeremy Banks.

Comment: @A.Franklin Excellent. I have added a reference to Jeremy's answer and I will also note this in the source code.